# How to develop an website on air?

Tags: php, git, web

Is there a way of developing an website "on air" using the yii framework? Or should I say, what is the best way of developing/testing an website that is already on air? I mean, without duplicating it, ie., a version "public"  and a "development" version, with duplicated "protected/" directories. How people usually do this kind of stuff?

Thanks!!

Comment: in one of directory create symbolic link with linux command `ln` http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ln.htm

Answer (score 1):

Seem you should use git to do it.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I could use git, but I don't have an idea on how to do two separate 'public' and 'devel' versions. If I checked out a branch (development one, for example), the devel would be publicly visible, ie., the 'devel' version would be the 'public'.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you need?